# What are the advantages of using Auto Layout with views created programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Auto Layout Constraints allow me to size and lay out views perfectly, without knowing beforehand what screen they will be rendered on. This works reasonably well when I'm drawing a UI on a Storyboard.

Let's move on to creating views programmatically.

My app is running, the interface has been rendered on the screen, I have all the necessary coordinates and the sizing has been done.
I would like to create a few views dynamically, for instance:

- a `UIImageView`, that appears at the press of a button, gets animated, then disappears
- a collection of custom `UIView`, created and laid out on the screen depending on the underlying data model (imagine a sequence of events here, arranged on a custom timeline)

In similar scenarios, I still tend to use the good old frames, e.g.:

```
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, w, h))
```

without adding any `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Is there any definite advantage of using constraints instead, given the added complexity, especially when you need to animate views?

Answer (score 0):

The most important aspects are when you actually calculate your frame (which method), if you want universal support and if you need to support various orientations.

Inside a viewController, if you print out your `self.view` frame in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, it might have different values. The final frame (for example, the one for iPhone 6 plus) is not calculated in `viewDidLoad`. So if you make your view setup there, the calculation will be wrong.

But with constraints, it does not matter where you add them. You might need to call `layoutIfNeeded` after the view changes, but you don't need to worry weather the frames have their final value.

For views that are visible only for a short time, auto layout could make a difference for different orientations. By using frames, you will have to update the frame of your temporary view in the orientation change callback.

Also, if you use auto layout in the storyboard, using static frames for views created programmatically might not give you the results you are expecting. But, of course, it depends on the particularities of your project.